# Click link to execute a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a function after a link has been clicked.

The link I would like to point to the function is the one with the `cancelLink` class.  The first link is here to show you as an example how I'm getting the AppointmentId the first link works by passing a parameter to another page.

I would like to be able to click the Cancel link and run a function on the current page.

Here are my links:

```
<a href="Invoices/InvoiceCreate.aspx?AppointmentId=${AppointmentId}">Invoice</a>&nbsp;|
<a href="#" class="cancelLink" data-attr=${AppointmentId}>Cancel</a>
```

Below is my click function which is under the document ready:

```
$('a.cancelLink').click(function () {
   var appointmentId = $(this).attr("data-attr");
   //var appointmentId = $(this).attr("appointmentId");
   MemberWebService.AppointmentStatusUpdate(appointmentId, 3, function () {

   window.location = 'AppointmentViewAll.aspx';
   });
 });
```

Currently code does not enter this click function, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Do you see any error on browser console?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Nope no errors on the browser console.

Comment: $('a.cancelLink').click(function (e) {e.preventDefault()}); write this and see if it works.

Comment: is #cancelLink on the page when the page is loaded, or is it rendered/loaded afterwards?  And if it is already loaded, are you doing `.click()` inside of a domReady?

Comment: Check out the usual suspects, such as you registering the handler before the DOM is ready or before the link element exists (if it is added dynamically).

Comment: @maverickosama92 How would i write that the brackets are a bit confusing?

Comment: try putting alert inside click handler as soon as you get appointmentId `alert(appointmentId);`

Comment: Please show the code where you include jQuery on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the onclick method to call a function and add parameters.

```
<a href="#" onclick="bindCancel(${AppointmentId})">Cancel</a>

function bindCancel(appointmentId) {
    MemberWebService.AppointmentStatusUpdate(appointmentId, 3, function () {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me. Here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hAErJLWHlHB0N1w2UkPU?p=preview). Have you tried put a 'console.log("sample test");' inside your click handler to see if it's firing? Could you please also post how did you wrap your code inside $(document).ready() ?

Did you do it this way?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a.cancelLink').click(function () {
       var appointmentId = $(this).attr("data-attr");
       //var appointmentId = $(this).attr("appointmentId");
       MemberWebService.AppointmentStatusUpdate(appointmentId, 3, function () {

       window.location = 'AppointmentViewAll.aspx';
   });
 });
});
```

Comment: My code looks the same as the code above wraped in the $(document.ready()) in the same way.

Comment: If you run $('a.cancelLink') inside browser console, what does it bring up?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('a.cancelLink').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var appointmentId = $(this).attr("data-attr");
   //var appointmentId = $(this).attr("appointmentId");
   MemberWebService.AppointmentStatusUpdate(appointmentId, 3, function () {

    window.location = 'AppointmentViewAll.aspx';
  });
});
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this, but my break point never enter inside this .click function.

Comment: Yes the link's are inside a template.

Comment: try to add some custom data-attr="12" and see it comes inside click or not?

Comment: Still does not move into my onclick?

Answer (score 0):

I found a few possible causes, see my comments;

HTML

```
<a href="Invoices/InvoiceCreate.aspx?AppointmentId=${AppointmentId}">Invoice</a>
<a href="#" class="cancelLink" data-attr="${AppointmentId}">Cancel</a> // Use quotes
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Only access elements once the DOM is loaded

  $(document).on('click', 'a.cancelLink', function(event) { // Try using on() instead of click() as you seem to be using some templating for creating the link ("${AppointmentId}").

    event.preventDefault(); // Don´t follow the link to #

    var appointmentId = $(this).data('attr'); // Use data() instead of attr()
    console.log(event.type, appointmentId); // View your console

    MemberWebService.AppointmentStatusUpdate(appointmentId, 3, function() {
       window.location = 'AppointmentViewAll.aspx';
    });
  });

});
```

See [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/).